# Egoic voice in head

Tags: right-mindfulness

It has been observed, all the egoic voices heard is same as the younger brother. When any positive resolution is made, for example, fasting on certain days, doing japa, abstaining from certain foods, going on pilgrimage & all positive things that will increase spirituality. This voice of younger brother is troubling since many years. Tried mindfulness, however this voice always triggers pain in the body, could see the soul very sad, as if any tantra is done. Please suggest any Buddhist way to get rid of these voices.

**Edit**:Just wanted to add something more to this experience.
It's not just voice sometimes, it is observed the body is overcome & actions of the body are controlled by another spirit(same as the younger brother). Kind of spooky, but it was observed many times.

Comment: Hey Christopher, does this voice only sound like your younger brother, or it is in fact coming from other person ?

Comment: It's exactly like the younger brother

Comment: I would add as short answer that the problem is not the voice put your desire to get rid of it. This desire is what makes you suffer, because you clearly don't get what you want. Give up the wanting, and the voice will no longer be an issue.

Comment: It's not just voice sometimes, it is observed the body is overcome & actions of the body are controlled by another spirit. Kind of spooky, but it was observed many times. Proper meditation should help. Please do suggest any medication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my analysis what you are calling as the voice of the younger brother is really the psychological concept of [super-ego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego#Super-ego). It's really a voice of your parents and your cultural conditioning.

I will suggest you start practising **Vipassana**. Only practising mindfulness will not help, you will end up being mindful of the voice and that will be a torture.

Attend a 10-day vipassana course, it's free of cost based on donation. Learn how to resolve our *sankaras*. Learn to resolve the knots tied deep within. Then practise for 6 months and do 2-3 more courses. I think you will be healed.

Also, practise forgiveness meditation towards your parents. You have to let-it-go, whatever happened, whatever was taught to you, that has to be let-go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Definitely will check on how to resolve Sankara's. Would like to add, the nature of the mind sometimes same as the father. .

Comment: Just a suggestion but, if its too bad go see the psychologist. There are lot many psychiatrist conditions diagnosed about voice in head. It can be cured through medicine.

Comment: Sure, will visit a psychiatrist

Answer (score 0):

Suffering has three parts: [greed, aversion and delusion](https://suttacentral.net/iti88/en/ireland). By hating the voice, you are suffering. If a younger brother brings aggravation, a younger brother can also bring kindness. Having aversion for one and greed for the other is suffering.  Both will make the voices stronger.

Instead, [be aware of your breathing](https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato) and simply observe that conviction of a persecuted self may be [a deeply constructed delusion arising out of a forgotten craving and delight](https://suttacentral.net/an10.93/en/thanissaro):

> Venerable sirs, whatever has been brought into being, is fabricated,
>   willed, dependently originated, that is inconstant. Whatever is
>   inconstant is stress. Whatever is stress is not me, is not what I am,
>   is not my self. Having seen this well with right discernment as it
>   actually is present, I also discern the higher escape from it as it
>   actually is present.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, take comfort in the fact that you're not the only one suffering from such a problem.

From [this page](http://www.hearing-voices.org/voices-visions/famous-people/), I found out that the actor Anthony Hopkins suffered from this too. He purportedly said:

> "I’ve always had a little voice in my head, particularly when I was
>   younger and less assured”, he said. “While onstage, during classical
>   theatre the voice would suddenly say, “Oh, you think you can do
>   Shakespeare, do you?” and he added; “Recently, I was being interviewed
>   on television and the voice inside my head said to me, “Who the hell
>   do you think you are. You’re just an actor, what the hell do you know
>   about anything”.

Apparently, hearing voices may or may not be related to mental health conditions, so it's good to get it checked with a medical professional.

Meghan Jisho Caughey, a sufferer of Schizophrenia (which may not be your condition) reported how Zen meditation helped her in [this blog entry](http://psychoticbuddha.blogspot.com/2015/04/zen-practice-and-schizophrenia.html):

> So this is what I have found during the hours on the cushion. First
>   of all, let me say, Zen practice, for me, is hardly ever relaxing. I
>   don’t do it because it feels good. Just in the last few years, due to
>   a better medication, it does occasionally feel somewhat peaceful. But
>   much of the time, it is simply uncomfortable to sit there, and stay on
>   the cushion.
>
> I sit, and the internal voices often get louder. It‘s challenging.
>
> I want to stop; I want to pay attention to the voices. They are
>   seductive.
>
> I try to count my breaths, if I can count to four, it is unusual.
>
> I switch to listening to sounds meditation. External sounds---the bird
>   in the tree outside, a car, the wind in a tree, my dog’s snoring. This
>   actually works quite well fairly often when I am hearing voices
>   because it competes with the voice; it changes the focus if I can do
>   it for a little while.
>
> Sometimes the voices or a body distortion will be really stubborn. I
>   am just stuck with it.
>
> There I am, on the cushion, no escape.
>
> So what I have learned to do is just to be there.
>
> I learned this in sesshin.
>
> Just to be there. Moment by moment. With all the Stuff. Whatever.
>
> I found out that it wasn’t going to kill me. And then I found out that
>   I could choose my attitude toward the Stuff. Chose the feeling–tone.
>   So now, the practice goes something like this:
>
> I’m sitting doing zazen and the scary perceptual stuff comes up, And I
>   recognize it, and I say to it, “Oh, so it’s you again!” And I lovingly
>   tell it,” Well, I’m putting the welcome mat out for you, just come
>   right on in!” And the scary stuff gets kind of smaller and not so
>   scary, and sort of shuffles off into a corner, not so bad, after all.
>
> Still, there are times when I just have to sit and it is like I am
>   sitting in a snowstorm, or a war, except the energy is inside.  So,
>   one might ask, why do I sit—if it is not peaceful—and there are not
>   more moments of bliss?
>
> Sometimes I ask myself this question, and what I get in touch with is
>   that by sitting that I somehow connect with my True Nature. For me
>   this is especially meaningful, because for years I thought that my
>   True Nature was my disease, schizophrenia. But deep down, I could hear
>   something else: Buddha Nature.
>
> When I was in my early forties—I am now fifty-one—I took the Precepts
>   and Refuge in the ceremony called Jukai. I was given two Dharma names
>   by my teacher. One name, Jisho, means compassion for all life. My
>   teacher made a point to say that I must have compassion for myself. 
>   The other name is Ahimsa: nonharming. This meant to me that I could no
>   longer act out self destructively, regardless of what the voices told
>   me to do. I had to change my life.
>
> I owe my life to this practice. My gratitude is beyond words. To sum
>   it up, I would say that my practice with schizophrenia is just moment
>   by moment, stay on the cushion with whatever comes up, and it is all
>   workable, if you just stick it out.